# Call different model images from same web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm starting from: How TO - Modal Images w3schools.com

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

I would like to call many different modals from one web page. TIA Sorry, I'm a clueless noob.

Found this:
https://blr.design/blog/multiple-modals/
and this:
https://codepen.io/JackZelig/pen/VPdQXJ

````
 <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div> ```
````

Comment: You would want to use class selector instead of ID. Then you would want to make use of `this` in JavaScript to define which element has been clicked. Then you can proceed with the logic in your link. Example of `this` in JS here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Martin. I managed to get both examples in the links above working. And I came to realize modals are not good for my need. For dozens of images, clicking open, clicking close is too much. Better a slideshow or light box. Thanks again.